# Tag Cleanup - Microsoft System Center Suite

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, cleanup

[scom](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scom), [sccm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sccm), and [scvmm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scvmm) all follow the same naming convention. DPM should as well.

[dpm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dpm) => [scdpm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scdpm)
[dpm-2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dpm-2010) -> [scdpm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scdpm)

[scom-2007-r2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scom-2007-r2) -> [scom](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scom)

[system-center-essentials](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/system-center-essentials) -> [sce](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sce)

I haven't seen any questions for the others, SC Service Manager, Opalis, AVIcode, or Advisor.

Comment: What do people think about seperating the `sc` part, so that it becomes `sc-om` and `sc-cm` and `sc-vmm`? As someone who uses a fair number of `sc` products, I'm kinda against it because everyone refers to it as `scom` and `scvmm`, but from an OCD point of view it could be better.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Yeah, they really should be ms-sc-om, ms-sc-cm, etc. But that's letting form get in the way of function. I got some pretty feverent pushback when I got the "FF" prepended to "TMG"... I'm thinking there would be more pushback on this one.

Comment: yeah, I hated the idea of putting FF on TMG as well. If I don't hear anything from anyone in a few hours I'll do the merge as you sugget.

Comment: If I were more familiar with the products myself I'd have a firmer opinion.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 in the MS community they're pretty well known by the sc??? acronyms. DPM was it's own product before MS formed the System Center suite (which it looks like they may be disolving now, forming a Cloud Management suite... *le sigh*) so the "DPM" stuck despite the product having System Center in the title... As long as the two DPM tags get merged/syn I don't really care, except for OCD for consistency.

Comment: @Chris S: Actually, you changed it to one-FTMG. As the primary contributor of answers for that product, I'm still bitter about it.

Comment: @TristanK - are you saying that one of the synonyms is incorrect?

Comment: @Mark Henderson: No, just inconsistent with the scheme suggested above. TMG-2010 was synonymed to ms-ftmg-2010 rather than ms-ff-tmg-2010 . I preferred TMG-2010, but was voted down. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)

Answer (score 0):

`scdpm` is a horrible name for a tag. It's not discoverable for new users, does not match with any google searches, and is cryptic even for existing users. Sccm is at least a common abbreviation, but the other less-common products need something better.

At very least, this should have been set up with a few tag synonyms before the abbreviation, to help new users fall into the pit of success for good tag names.

Comment: DPM is a syn of SCDPM, you can just type in DPM and get the expected result... Are you just complaining, or do you have a suggestion to improve the situation?

Comment: I'd like to see the abbreviations used as synonyms for the longer form of the name. Those who expect the abbreviation can still end up with a valid tag, but google and new users both tend to prefer the long form (ie: `Data-Protection-Manager`).