# Rename scdpm tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Quick: what does "scdpm" mean?

If you guessed System Center Data Protection Manager, you're better with acronyms than I am.  I found the tag through this question:
[Why does co-locating data use so much storage space?](https://serverfault.com/questions/366882/why-does-co-locating-data-use-so-much-storage-space)

I'm not sure what new name to give it (especially as there's already a core `system-center` tag), but this name sucks. We need something that's more readable and will match better with google searches. Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

See http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2377/tag-cleanup-microsoft-system-center-suite

Consistent with the other System Center products, it was named SCDPM, just like SCOM, SCCM, SCVMM, SCSM, SCE... They're all SC___.

I don't see how [system-center](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/system-center) adds any value; it should be burninated IMHO.

Comment: scdpm is a horrible name for a tag. It's not discoverable for new users, does not match with any google searches, and cryptic even for existing users. Sccm is at least a common abbreviation, but the other less-common products need something better. But maybe I should say all this in the other question :(

Comment: I agree with Chris that [tag:system-center] is worthless (System Center ***WHAT?***), but "scdpm" is also a lousy name.  Perhaps the real solution here is to create a more reasonable synonym (it's already got [tag:dpm] and [tag:dpm-2010] - what do y'all call it when you're not disparaging it?)

Comment: Would even those who use the product readily know what "scdpm" is or that it might be the appropriate tag to use? Looking in from the outside it seems to me to be a case of taking an abbreviation too far. Consistency in naming tags does not always produce the best and/or most desirable results.